# Plotting data from different datasets using plotnine and pandas

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, data-science, python-ggplot, plotnine

First off, I think it would be helpful to offer some background about what I want to do. I have a time-series dataset that describes air quality in a region, with hour resolution. Each row is an observation, each column is a different parameter (eg. Temperature, Pressure, Particulate matter, etc.) I want to take an average of observations for each hour in the day, across the entire five year dataset. However, I first need to distinguish between summer and winter observations. Here are a few rows for reference:

```
            Date      Time  WSA  WSV  WDV  WSM   SGT   T2M  T10M  DELTA_T   PBAR  SRAD     RH  PM25         AQI
0     2015-01-01  00:00:00  0.9  0.2  334  3.2  70.9  29.2  29.1     -0.1  740.4     8  102.5  69.0  157.970495
1     2015-01-01  01:00:00  1.5  0.7  129  4.0  58.8  29.6  29.2     -0.4  740.2     8  102.5  23.5   74.974249
2     2015-01-01  02:00:00  0.8  0.8   70  2.7  18.0  28.7  28.3     -0.4  740.3     7  102.2  40.1  112.326633
3     2015-01-01  03:00:00  1.1  1.0   82  3.4  21.8  28.2  27.8     -0.4  740.1     6  102.0  31.1   90.957082
4     2015-01-01  04:00:00  1.0  0.8   65  4.7  34.3  27.3  27.2     -0.2  739.7     6  101.7  13.7   54.364807
...          ...       ...  ...  ...  ...  ...   ...   ...   ...      ...    ...   ...    ...   ...         ...
43175 2016-12-30  19:00:00  1.7  0.7  268  4.1  63.6  33.8  34.1      0.3  738.8     8  100.7  38.4  108.140704
43176 2016-12-30  20:00:00  1.5  0.1  169  3.3  77.5  33.2  33.7      0.5  738.7     9  101.0  27.2   82.755365

43177 2016-12-30  21:00:00  1.4  0.5  278  4.0  65.7  32.5  32.8      0.3  738.6     9  101.4  42.5  118.236181
43178 2016-12-30  22:00:00  2.8  2.7  277  6.5  16.7  33.2  33.3      0.1  738.6     9  101.6  25.2   78.549356
43179 2016-12-30  23:00:00  1.9  0.3  241  4.2  74.2  31.0  31.6      0.6  738.4     9  100.4  18.7   64.879828

[43180 rows x 15 columns]
```

I have tried splitting the dataset into two based on season, and plotting each separately. This works, but I cannot manage to make the plot display a legend.

```
mask = (df['Date'].dt.month > 3) & (df['Date'].dt.month < 10)

summer = df[mask]
winter = df[~mask]

summer = summer.groupby(summer['Time'].dt.hour).mean().reset_index()
winter = winter.groupby(winter['Time'].dt.hour).mean().reset_index()

p = (
    ggplot(mapping=aes( x='Time', y='PM25')) +
    geom_point(data=summer, color='red')+
    geom_point(data=winter, color='blue')
    )

print(p)
```

Plotting with separate dataframes:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W75kk.png

I did some more research, and learned that plotnine/ggplot can color-code data points based on one of their attributes. This approach requires the data to be a single dataset, so I added a parameter specifying the season. However, when I group by hour, this 'Season' attribute is removed. I assume it is because you cannot take the mean of non-numeric data. As such, I find myself in a bit of a paradox.
Here is the my attempt at keeping the data together and adding a 'Season' column:

```
df.insert(0,'Season', 0)

summer = (df['Date'].dt.month > 3) & (df['Date'].dt.month < 10)

df['Season'] = df.where(summer, other='w')
df['Season'] = df.where(~summer, other='s')

df = df.groupby(df['Time'].dt.hour).mean()

print(df)

p = (
    ggplot(data = df, mapping=aes( x='Time', y='PM25', color='Season')) +
    geom_point()
    )

print(p)
```

When I try to run this, it raises the following, and if I inspect the dataframe all non-numeric paramters have been removed:

```
plotnine.exceptions.PlotnineError: "Could not evaluate the 'color' mapping: 'Season' (original error: name 'Season' is not defined)"
```

Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Data provided has been saved to airq.csv. Besides to Season column, Hour column has been included. Code provided has been used. 'Hour' and 'Season' have to be provided in groupby function. Two plotnine.ggplot possibilities are provided. Fist using geom_point, and second one adding facet_wrap. Theme customization has been included for each case.

```
from plotnine import *
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('airq.csv', parse_dates=[0,1])
df.insert(0,'Season', 0)
summer = (df['Date'].dt.month > 3) & (df['Date'].dt.month < 9)
df['Season'] = df.where(summer, other='Winter')
df['Season'] = df.where(~summer, other='Summer')
df['Hour'] = df['Time'].dt.hour
df = df.groupby(['Hour', 'Season']).mean().reset_index()
custom_axis = theme(axis_text_x = element_text(color="grey", size=6, angle=90, hjust=.3),
                    axis_text_y = element_text(color="grey", size=6), 
                    plot_title = element_text(size = 25, face = "bold"), 
                    axis_title = element_text(size = 10)  
                    ) 
(
    ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x='Hour', y='PM25',
                          color='Season')) + geom_point() +
    custom_axis + ylab("Particulate matter 2.5 micrometres") + xlab("Hour") + labs(title="PM air quality report")
)
```

[image: geom_point option]

```
custom_axis = theme(axis_text_x = element_text(color="grey", size=6, angle=90, hjust=.3),
                    axis_text_y = element_text(color="grey", size=6), 
                    plot_title = element_text(size = 25, face = "bold"), 
                    axis_title = element_text(size = 10), 
                    panel_spacing_y=.4, 
                    figure_size=(8, 4) 
                    ) 

(
    ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x='Hour', y='PM25')) + geom_point(alpha=1) + facet_wrap('Season') + 
    custom_axis + ylab("Particulate matter 2.5 micrometres") + xlab("Hour") + labs(title="PM air quality report")
)
```

[image: facet_wrap addition]

Comment: My goal is to have the seasons share a single plot. I ended up giving up on plotnine and using seaborn.